# Override Json deserializing a number with a leading zero as a decimal and not an octal value

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I am generating a json object,

```
{
   "number":0100
}
```

When this object is deserialized in C# using Newtonsoft.Json, **0100** is treated as an octal number because of the leading zero.
Is there a way to override this functionality and make it consider the number as a decimal integer?

Comment: What is the data type for number? Share some more code.

Comment: I am trying to deserialize it as an int

Comment: put your json here http://json2csharp.com/ and find get your class.

Comment: Why are you generating your numbers with leading zeros?

Comment: Indeed this is invalid JSON.  The JSON spec says that leading zeros are not allowed.  It is a bug in your generator if it generates them like that.  (Newtonsoft.Json is also buggy, but that only matters because of your bug.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've looked at `JsonTextReader.ParseNumber()` (the method where the "magic" of number reading happen). I'll say that it isn't doable. The octal case is especially handled

```
bool flag2 = c == '0' ...
```

and then

```
long value2 = text2.StartsWith("0x", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? 
                  Convert.ToInt64(text2, 16) : 
                  Convert.ToInt64(text2, 8); // Here OCTAL!!!
```

I haven't found any way to override this method (other than re-writing all the `Read()` method that does *everything* in Json parsing)

Comment: I would recommend looking for an alternative to Newtonsoft.  Maintaining your own "fork" to fix egregious interoperability bugs that the author is unwilling to fix seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 12):

If Newtonsoft.Json does that, then it is a bug.  According to the JSON syntax as documented on http://json.org:

> *"A number is very much like a C or Java number, **except that the octal and hexadecimal formats are not used**."*

and the syntax graph does not allow a number to have a leading non-significant zero.

[RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) Section 2.4. agrees:

> *"Octal and hex forms are not allowed.  Leading zeros are not allowed."*

So in fact, your use of leading zeros is not valid JSON at all ... according to the RFC.

---

So, to answer your question:

> Is there a way to override this functionality and make it consider the number as a decimal integer?

Probably not.  Moreover, you *shouldn't* do it.  Instead you should fix the JSON, or complain to the people who are generating it that it is not conformant.

<strike>You should also report this as a bug in Newtonsoft.Json.</strike>.  Don't bother.  The author does not acknowledge this as a bug.  I would advise switching to a JSON library that implements the JSON spec correctly.

---

**ADVICE FOR JSON IMPLEMENTERS**

The JSON specs (both version) clearly say that hexadecimal and octal forms are not allowed.

If you add support for hex and/or octal (or some other unofficial "extension") to your JSON parser, you are adding to the fragmentation of the JSON standard.  This is bad.

It is also a bad idea because many end-users are surprised when a non-significant leading zero is treated as an octal marker.  This leads to Questions like this ... where (I'm guessing) the OP's end-users have been burned, and are requesting him to fix >>his<< code to handle leading zeros "properly".

The correct behavior here is to **strictly** implement the JSON spec, and reject any number with a non-significant leading zero.  (Personally, I'd implement special-case error messages for this and for "0x..." hexadecimal forms.)

Comment: But by looking at that graph, 0100 isn't a number :) if you look you can have 0 or [1-9][0-9]* (ok... useless comment, you added the RFC)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. But since newtonsoft.Json allows leading zeros and treats them as octal numbers, is there a way to override that?

Comment: @Naren No, there isn't a way to override this behavior in Json.Net

Comment: See https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/924 & https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1057

Comment: Unfortunately, the developer doesn't seem inclined to fix this (IMO) misfeature.  He has closed both issues.  This might explain why the NewtonSoft.Json implementation is not listed on http://json.org.  At any rate, there are lots of alternatives to it.

Comment: This feature of Newtonsoft.Json is actually pretty dangerous. More and more configurations are stored as json files and edited manually. If the user unconsiously will add a leading zero (and by chance will not use digits 8 and 9), he will have no clue that his number is no more decimal.

Answer (score -1):

What is your .net framework?

You can use DataContractJsonSerializer object to deserialize that json. 
I tried. It worked.

With .net 3.5: it's in System.ServiceMode.Web assembly.

With .net 4+: it's in System.Runtime.Serialization.Json assembly.

Example:

```
[DataContract]
public class TestObject
{
    private int _id;
    private string _name;
    private decimal _number;
    [DataMember]
    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
        }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
        }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public decimal Number
    {
        get
        {
            return _number;
        }
        set
        {
            _number = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Test

```
private string jsonText = "{\"Id\": 1, \"Name\": \"kanozuki\", \"Number\":\"0100\"}";

TestObject obj = Deserialise<TestObject>(jsonText);

public T Deserialise<T>(string json)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer deserializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
        {
            T result = (T)deserializer.ReadObject(stream);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Result
    
    `obj.Id:1
    obj.Name:kanozuki
    obj.Number:100`

Comment: That JSON isn't equivalent to the OP's, yours has `Number` with a string value.