# How to convert new Date(year, month, day) overload with JSON.Net

Tags: c#, datetime, json.net

I'm trying to parse JSON file where dates are defined as [JavaScript objects](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp) :

```
new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

so I did try to parse it with the [JavaScriptDateTimeConverter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_JavaScriptDateTimeConverter.htm)

test.json:

```
{"data" : [{"Date" : new Date(2015, 06, 01, 00, 00, 00)}]}
```

c#:

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"c:\test.json"))
{
  JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
  serializer.Converters.Add(new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
  Rootobject deserializedRoot = (Rootobject)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(Rootobject));
}
```

Unfortunatly I'm receiving this error :

> Unexpected token parsing date. Expected EndConstructor, got Integer. Path 'data[0].Date[1](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp)', line 13, position 30.

From my understanding JSON.Net expect at best a `new Date(52231943)` but doesn't  handle constructor overloads of Javascript Date() object.

Is there any known way to convert the `new Date(year, month, day)`?

Comment: In the file that you are parsing, are these dates always contained within an array as above?

Comment: Please note that this is in fact not legal "json" - http://json.org. It may be a valid Javascript object, but not json.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - you're right, nevertheless Json.NET supports this sort of syntax.  See http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/02/20/good-date-times-with-json-net and http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create your own subclass of [`JavaScriptDateTimeConverter.cs`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/JavaScriptDateTimeConverter.cs) like so:

```
public class JavaScriptYMDDateTimeConverter : JavaScriptDateTimeConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Type type = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) ?? objectType);
        bool isNullable = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) != null);

        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token == null || token.Type == JTokenType.Null)
        {
            if (!isNullable)
                throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Null value for type {0} at path {1}", objectType.Name, reader.Path));
            return null;
        }
        if (token.Type != JTokenType.Constructor)
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Invalid Date constructor \"{0}\" at path {1}", token.ToString(), reader.Path));
        }
        var constructor = (JConstructor)token;
        if (!string.Equals(constructor.Name, "Date", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Invalid Date constructor \"{0}\" at path {1}", token.ToString(), reader.Path));
        }

        var values = constructor.Values().ToArray();

        if (values.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Invalid Date constructor \"{0}\" at path {1}", token.ToString(), reader.Path));
        }
        else if (values.Length == 1)
        {
            // Assume ticks
            using (var subReader = constructor.CreateReader())
            {
                while (subReader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartConstructor)
                    subReader.Read();
                return base.ReadJson(subReader, objectType, existingValue, serializer); // Use base class to convert
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var year = (values.Length > 0 ? (int)values[0] : 0);
            var month = (values.Length > 1 ? (int)values[1] : 0) + 1; // c# months go from 1 to 12, JavaScript from 0 to 11
            var day = (values.Length > 2 ? (int)values[2] : 0);
            var hour = (values.Length > 3 ? (int)values[3] : 0);
            var min = (values.Length > 4 ? (int)values[4] : 0);
            var sec = (values.Length > 5 ? (int)values[5] : 0);
            var ms = (values.Length > 6 ? (int)values[6] : 0);

            // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date
            // Note: Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one argument, the specifed arguments represent local time.
            var dt = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, min, sec, ms, DateTimeKind.Local);
            if (type == typeof(DateTimeOffset))
                return new DateTimeOffset(dt);
            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Here `ReadJson()` loads the token into a [`JConstructor`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JConstructor.htm), checks that the [constructor name](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JConstructor_Name.htm) is `Date`, then parses the children.

Note I did not override `WriteJson`, so this converter will write in the same style as `JavaScriptDateTimeConverter`, with the ticks appearing as the single argument to the constructor.

Use it in place of `JavaScriptDateTimeConverter()`.

Comment: Works as expected except JToken.Load() parse leading zeros from 00 to 07 but crash with 08 and 09. I fix it upfront with :
var json = Regex.Replace(input, "( )0*([1-9][0-9]*|0)", "$1$2");

Comment: @lucian.jp - Glad it's working for you.  Would you mind sharing an example of the JSON that causes the crash?

Comment: {"data" : [{"Date" : new Date(2015, 06, 08, 00, 00, 00)}]}

Comment: @lucian.jp - I found that `JsonTextReader` interprets a number starting with `0` as an **Octal**, so `08` throws an exception.  (According to the [JSON standard](http://json.org/) numbers should not have a leading zero so this is an extension to the standard.)  Looks like there's no workaround either: [Override Json deserializing a number with a leading zero as a decimal and not an octal value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29048110/override-json-deserializing-a-number-with-a-leading-zero-as-a-decimal-and-not-an).  So your Regex.Replace() may be the right idea.

Comment: Strange that it works from 00 to 07 tho. Thank you anyway

Comment: @lucian.jp - Octal is base 8 so there's no `8` digit in Octal.