# When using a JsonWriter, what's the purpose of WriteStartConstructor?

Tags: c#, json, constructor, json.net

Title says it all.  I see it (with its corresponding end) spits out the following...

```
new Foo(
)
```

...but I don't understand what the `new` actually does when deserializing.  The docs just say it writes a Json constructor, but not what a Json constructor *is*!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method was introduced as part of an enhancement to allow Json.NET to parse date literals when represented with JavaScript constructors like so: [`new Date(1234656000000)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).  For details, see [Serializing Dates in JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm).  Even though this syntax is not strictly valid according to the [JSON standard](http://json.org/), apparently there was enough demand to support it that Newtonsoft put it in.

Thus it was necessary to add low-level methods to [`JsonWriter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter.htm) and [`JsonReader`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader.htm) to write and read literals in this format.  (Strictly speaking I suppose writing could have been tacked on to [`WriteRaw`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_WriteRaw.htm), this would have been kind of hackey, and anyway there is no method `ReadRaw`)  [`WriteStartConstructor`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_WriteStartConstructor.htm) is one of these low-level utility methods.

There is also a high-level Linq-to-JSON class [`JConstructor`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JConstructor.htm) to represent this syntax.  You can use it to support other specific JavaScript constructors as needed, for instance see [How to convert new Date(year, month, day) overload with JSON.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31577833/how-to-convert-new-dateyear-month-day-overload-with-json-net/31578239#31578239).