# Custom serialization of Date objects with JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, serialization

I have an object that I'm serializing to string with JavaScriptSerializer.  I've already registered a custom converter to omit null properties, but I also want to change how Date properties are rendered.

I want the date property to appear something like

```
{
   DateProperty = new Date(2019, 0, 31)
}
```

Instead of:

```
{
   DateProperty = "\/Date(1483776000000)\/";
}
```

Is it possible to customize how the JavaScriptSerializer serializes DateTime, or is there another serializer?  I'm hoping to not hve to go to a 3rd party serializer.

Comment: `{ DateProperty = new Date(2019, 0, 31) }` is not well-formed JSON.  Try uploading it to https://jsonlint.com/ and you will get errors. `JavaScriptSerializer` cannot generate such badly-formed JSON.  However, the [tag:json.net] library can parse and generate psuedo-JSON in this format, see e.g. [How to convert new Date(year, month, day) overload with JSON.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31578239/3744182).  That answer discusses how to deserialize JSON in such a format, but could be extended to serialization.  Is that what you need?

Comment: Also, property names such as `DateProperty` must be quoted as required by the JSON standard https://json.org/.  Do you really require them to be unquoted?

Answer (score 0):

That date format you want to  change it's Microsoft format and JavaScriptSerializer convert object to JSON format. Please see this link for more details and hope can help you

[Dates in JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm)