# Validate if string is valid json (fastest way possible) in .NET Core 3.0

Tags: json, .net-core

I know i can use an external library(newtonsoft) with a try/catch to check if a string is valid json structure.  I do not want to deserialize to an object (since the json can be one or many properties) point is to just make sure its valid json.

I would prefer to use the System.Text.Json  but not sure what would be the best, TryParseValue, JsonDocument, etc

Comment: I don't think System.Text.Json has functionality for this yet, sadly. I'd go with JsonSchemas from NewtonsoftSoft in your case. If you are okay with a try .. catch solution, you could do something like this `try { return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonData); } catch (JsonException) { return default; }` with System.Text.Json

Comment: 1) Do you mean "valid" as in "well-formed"?  Or "valid" as in "matching some schema"?  2) If you need to check for JSON being well-formed, note that each JSON parser has slight idiosyncrasies in how it parses JSON (See e.g. [json net leading zeros (disable base-cast)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37561583) and [Support "strict mode" for RFC7159 parsing #646](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/646)) so it would be better to match your validator with your eventual serializer.

Comment: Use stack, hashsets etc.

Comment: "fastest way possible" is important especially if you would like to check inside a loop. Throwing an exception is a performance killer here.

Answer (score 14):

If your JSON is in a `string` and you are using `System.Text.Json` then probably the best way to check the JSON is well-formed would be to use `JsonDocument.Parse`. For example:

```cs
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool IsJson(this string source)
    {
        if (source == null)
            return false;

        try
        {
            using (JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.Parse(source))
            {
                // dispose any created doc
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (JsonException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldnt get it to work. If you're using this extension inside a method that already has a try catch then it doesnt seem to catch this inner exception so the boolean is never returned

Comment: @OJB1 I think you might want to look more carefully at your calling code. Thanks

Comment: throwing exception is really slow. Use JsonDocument.TryParseValue instead

Comment: @Tri why slow, are you testing millions of strings or something? Also, using TryParseValue will require you have a Utf8JsonReader created rather than a simple string which this example has (so there's a cost there instead). Beware the anti-pattern of premature optimization ;-)

Comment: @bytedev generally throwing exception is really slow. You are correct, depending on the use case, if the de/serialization only happens occasionally, definitely your case works. But if someone has to do it across a list of items, then throwing exception is a problem.

Answer (score 4):

An small improvement in @bytedev answer, disposing JsonDocument based on [Microsoft JsonDocument remark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument?view=net-5.0#remarks):

> This class utilizes resources from pooled memory to minimize the impact of the garbage collector (GC) in high-usage scenarios. Failure to properly dispose this object will result in the memory not being returned to the pool, which will increase GC impact across various parts of the framework

```
public static bool IsJsonValid(this string json)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(json))
        return false;

    try
    {
        using var jsonDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(json);
        return true;
    }
    catch (JsonException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This example has worked for me using .NET Core 3.1 and will throw an exception if a string is not well-formed JSON:

```cs
string json = "{ \"TestKey\": \"TestValue\" }";

// Ensure the string is valid JSON.
var js = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();
js.Deserialize(new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(json)));
```

Comment: Saying a single `throw;` straight after a single catch is redundant. You can remove the whole `try`/`catch` and the code will run exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks - `try` / `catch` now removed!

Answer (score 2):

I use Utf8JsonReader and simply call TrySkip() on the root object; this will check that it's at least well formed.

Comment: This answer could use some elaboration or code example.

Answer (score 1):

Code for @lidgren's answer:

```
public static void CheckJsonValid(ReadOnlySpan<byte> data)
{
    var reader = new Utf8JsonReader(data);
    reader.Read();
    reader.Skip();
}
```

Will throw a `JsonException` if there is any invalid JSON data.

This should be by far the fastest way to do it and should allocate absolutely nothing, I believe.