# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to string Error

Tags: c#, json.net

Deserialization object to string first row is ok, the second fail with error "Input string '00577028' is not a valid number. Path '', line 1, position 8.", inner exception: "Additional non-parsable characters are at the end of the string."

```cs
object o1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("00577027", typeof(System.String));
```

```cs
object o2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("00577028", typeof(System.String));
```

Why it fails to deserialize to string?

Comment: Because a JSON string needs to be quoted. You could deserialize `@"""00577208"""` that way. The reason deserializing the first attempt "succeeds" is because your number is parsed as octal (base 8), which is almost certainly not what you intended; JavaScript's inclusion of that is a joke that never gets old.

Comment: ok, I understand that, but i'm using second parameter "Type" which is by documentation "The Type of object being deserialized." So why is there any conversion to number if I say, that it is string....

Comment: 1) The literal `00577027` is not a well-formed JSON string because it's not quoted.

Comment: 2) It's not a well-formed JSON number *because it has leading zeros*.  The JSON standard does not permit leading zeros, see https://www.json.org/json-en.html.  Note that Json.NET has extended the JSON standard to interpret numbers with a single leading zero as being in Octal format, see [Deserialize number prefixed with a leading zero #2035](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2035) and [json net leading zeros (disable base-cast)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37561583/3744182).  But your number has ***two*** leading zeros.

Comment: (Should I write that as an answer, or is it enough to close as a duplicate of the linked question?)

Comment: So, why is there a second parameter  "The Type of object being deserialized." if it is ignored...

Comment: It's intended to allow you to specify a complex type (like a custom class); you can't use it to override how parsing happens.