# Aspnet Mvc decimal serialization error

Tags: c#, validation, controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a post method that accepts object containing decimal property as below

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateDto createDto)
{
    ...do stuff here
}

public class CreateDto
{
    [Required]
    public string Id{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal? Rate{ get; set; }
}
```

when a value containing leading 0 being passed in for Rate field, eg: 0015, it is always coming in as 10.

Would appreciate if somebody could explain this phenomena.

Comment: Good practice: append `Async` to every asnychronous method for clarity, i.e. the name should be `CreateAsync`.

Comment: if your version of MVC uses Json.NET, I think this is the issue: [NewtonSoft is not able to serialize integers 0008 and 0009 when passed in this format. #1385](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1385): *Yes, Json.NET, as with some other JSON parsers, is liberal in that it allows leading zeros before numbers that are all in the range [0-7], and treats them as **octal**, to match the sort of results one would get using eval in javascript.  **The JSON standard bans leading zeros in any case other than the integer zero or where zero is immediately followed by a decimal point.***

Comment: See also [Override Json deserializing a number with a leading zero as a decimal and not an octal value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29048110/3744182).  In fact is this a duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies within aspnet core mvc JSON parser which allows leading zeros before numbers that are all in the range [0-7], and treats them as octal, to match the sort of results one would get using eval in javascript.

This behaviour contradicts with guildlines stated in on http://json.org:

> "A number is very much like a C or Java number, except that the octal
>   and hexadecimal formats are not used."

and the syntax graph does not allow a number to have a leading non-significant zero.

RFC 4627 Section 2.4. agrees:

> "Octal and hex forms are not allowed. Leading zeros are not allowed."

So in short, the only way is to use JSON parser that implements the Json specs correctly.

Reference: [Override Json deserializing a number with a leading zero as a decimal and not an octal value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29048110/override-json-deserializing-a-number-with-a-leading-zero-as-a-decimal-and-not-an)