# How to Deserialize json into an object without specifying the key as a field inside the object?

Tags: json, .net-core, json.net

I have Json coming from an api and i want to Deserialize it into an object, however the json looks like this:

```
{
  "ticket_metric": {
   some json fields etc
}
```

I have a class that maps to the objects inside the ticket_metric, how do i map to it without having to create a root object with a ticket_metric field inside it.

Comment: Deserialize to a dictionary, ie. something like `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, YourClass>>(json)`.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen that is a good idea :), but is there not a better way using attributes i cant seem to find one >.<.

Comment: Well, you can create a root type with a property, and then use an attribute, `[JsonProperty("ticket_metric")]`.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen that is exactly what im trying to avoid XD, i dont want to create a whole new object.

Comment: Then you deserialize into a dictionary.

Comment: Or you use `JObject.Parse(json)`, and then go grab the internal object using its indexer, like `obj["ticket_metric"].ToObject<YourClass>()`.

Comment: if you don't want to use a dictionary, and the name `ticket_metric` is known in advance, use an anonymous type: `JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, new { ticket_metric = default(TicketMetricType) } ).ticket_metric` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53636937/3744182) to [Parse JSON without declaring model class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53636516/3744182).

Comment: Deserializing to an anonymous type or a dictionary will be more performant than the `JObject.Parse(json)` + `obj["ticket_metric"].ToObject<YourClass>()` combination because the latter requires the JSON be completely loaded into an intermediate `JToken` hierarchy.