# Newtonsoft Serialize: strings with leading zeros

Tags: c#, json, .net, serialization, logic

I have a short question:

Why does this work

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>("768")
```

But this not

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>("0768")
```

Comment: This might be helpful:  http://ostack.cn/?qa=635144/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override Json deserializing a number with a leading zero as a decimal and not an octal value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29048110/override-json-deserializing-a-number-with-a-leading-zero-as-a-decimal-and-not-an)

Comment: Leading `0` on numbers is not to JSON spec unless it's just a `0.xxx` decimal, see https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Json string should have 2 sets of "", try this

```
string s= Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>("\"0768\""); // 0768
```

if it has one set only, json deserializes string as number

```
int i= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int>("768"); //768
```

but for some reasons, any number that starts from zero  causes an exception

```
int i= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int>("0768");
```

and it is a well known bug that is in Json documentation

but if you try this, you will get an exception

```
string s= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>("abc")
```

this is ok

```
string s= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>("\"abc\""); //abc
```